# Connecting Mini GSM/GPRS Breakout 800L to Raspberry Pi model 4B

Tags: pi-4, gsm

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi to a sim card that I bought so that is can send an SMS and access the internet, but I am struggling to connect the sim module to my Pi. I have attached a GPIO pin layout as well as how I think I should connect it, but I am very new to microelectronics and am nervous that I damage the circuitry. The number in the brackets is which pin I think it shold connect to. This is where I got the module from however all their documentation is for Adrinos. (https://www.robotics.org.za/113990111?search=Mini%20GSM%2FGPRS%20Breakout%20800L)

Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: You might like to search "SIM800" in this forum to learn how other newbies are settinp up things for Rpi3B+. Or you can read my answers to the following questions for Rpi4B SIM7600 configuration. (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/using-3-sim800c-gsm-hat-on-1-raspberry-pi-3b, (2) 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103785/sim7600-4g-hat-rpi3b-setup-problem For newbies, I would recommend to use USB to UART adapter to talk to SIM/8/900/7600. Good luck and cheers..

Comment: To draw the power to the SIM800 from the Raspberry Pi is a BAD IDEA! The current peaks a SIM800 can have is exceeding the capability of the power a Raspberry Pi can spare for external devices.

Comment: Ah yes, I very much agree.  That is why I almost never use HAT. As you can see from my SIM7600 HAT setup, I don't use it as a HAT. I don't even use Rpi's on board UART, I only use USB to UART adpater. To repeat, I almost never use Tpi's on board 40 pin connector 3V3/5V0 power rail.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I am going to look for one of those adapters.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice SIM800 project. Cheers.