# Green light always on after a while for Raspberry pi 3 Model B V 1.2 2015

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-desktop, power-light

I boot the raspberry pi correctly, the red light is on (solid light) and the green light blinks. After a while, (it can be few hours or a couple of days) the green light stays solid and it does not blink anymore.

No data was recorded during the period of solid green light. I re-boot the raspberry pi and it works again: solid red light and the green light blinks.

I read some forums, someone says that the SD card may be corrupted, I should have to change it, but noone has this specific problem and on top of that with this type of raspberry pi.

Is anyone can help me?

Comment: Well there are many reasons.  One reason is that your Rpi "freezes" because a couple of other reasons, including: (1) Rpi runs out of resources, such as stack overflow, heap, memory segment, socket, memory "leaking" or related resource problems.  Or there are hardware related problems, including power supply unstable, noise, back EMF, EMI etc.  A general prevention/cure is use a watchdog timer. This Q&A explains the use of a watchdog timer. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99584/cut-power-on-a-remote-raspberry-pi-3-via-another-raspi.

Comment: By default the green light flickers to show SD card activity.  No flicker, no activity.  Have you a question?

Comment: When the green light is steady on then please execute the command `journalctl -b -e` and look if you can find any messages that may belong to the problem.