# How to track why two RPi's are constantly "freezing"...?

Tags: crash

I have two RPi's, one 3B+ and one 4 8GB. Both run updated Raspbian with Node-Red, VNCServer, No-ip DUC and have SSH enabled. No mouse or display connected to any of them.
The 3B+ serves as the "sensor grid" and the 4 runs a GUI and statistics collecting data through API calls via Node-Red.

The 3B+ has previously been running fine and I then used IBM Cloud Node-Red for GUI but bought a 4 to run the GUI this June.

Since the "refresh" of the system something has clearly happened as the both of them "freezes" and stops operating. It happens once or twice a day and after restart all runs fine and I can't detect any high CPU or memory leak or something "obvious".

The "freezing" means that they are completely dead but not completely crashed as often the VNC connects but it says that there is no desktop running. Also I sometimes get the SSH connection (login) but then the terminal isn't responding to any commands.

How can I try and figure out why they both are acting this way?
Which logs or what to check?

SD card would of course be an obvious place to start but I already changed SD in the 4 and that both SD cards would give up at the same time feels too much of a coincident...

Any pointers in where to start looking?

EDIT:
I found an older backup (about a year ago) of the SD card for the `3B+` that I restored from and now it is stable!
I've set a timer that will cut power to the `4` which cuts power off/on for 15 minutes each night and then it runs fine for 24 hrs...

Comment: This might help: "Rpi freezes every now and then, how to fix it with a watchdog? - Rpi SE":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99584/rpi-freezes-every-now-and-then-how-to-fix-it-with-a-watchdog. Cheers.

Comment: Do both of them freeze at the same time? How are they connected to each other and to your Computer/Laptop  (Hub, Switch, WLAN, Internet)? Could the connection be the problem. Perhaps the WLAN Router has some Problems. There are also some problems with newer Linux Kernels (5.2 and 5.3) but as far as I know, Raspbian uses older 4.x Kernels. Can you add a Keyboard, mouse and Monitor to one of the raspis to see if it is locally accessible when it freezes over the network?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the old installation and the refreshed one? Do you have the old installation still available? I would consider to compare the installed programs and versions with `dpkg --list` (of course filtered with a script).

Comment: Sorry for the late come back! See my Edit in the question. I've also set the Watchdog according to the suggestion but it hasn't shown me any useful information. It's just like it stops doing stuff, like it falls a sleep...